# How to get the last 2 characters of a string with last character being A or B and second to the last character being 1-360? (REGEX GREP)

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I'm not really using regex in a daily basis and I'm still new to this.

For example, I have these strings and this is the format of the strings:

APPLE20B**50A**
APPLE30A**60B**
APPLE12B**5B**
APPLE360A**360B**
APPLE**56B**

Basically, I want to get the last letter (A or B) and the digit before the last letter (or a digit after the letter/before the digit which is also A or B too). There are also a format like APPLE56B that doesn't have digit+letter in the middle.

****Expected Output****:

```
50A
60B
5B
360B
56B
```

I tried `grep -o '.\{2\}$'` but it only outputs the last 2 characters:

```
0A
0B
5B
0B
6B
```

and obviously, it's not dynamic for the digits. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -o` would indeed work with the correct pattern

```bash
grep -oP '[0-9]+[AB]$'
```

With Perl,

```bash
perl -nle'print $& if /[0-9]+[AB]$/'
```

```bash
perl -nle'print for /([0-9]+[AB])$/'
```

In all cases, you can provide the input via STDIN or by passing a file name to read as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bash
cat input-file | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if (m/([0-9]+[AB])$/)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU grep):

```
grep -o '\(360\|3[0-5][0-9]\|[1-2][0-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\|[1-9]\)[AB]\>' file
```

This will print each value on a separate line from `1A/1B` to `360A/360B`.

To space separate these values use:

```
grep -o '\(360\|3[0-5][0-9]\|[1-2][0-9][0-9]\|[1-9][0-9]\|[1-9]\)[AB]\>' file |
paste -sd' '
```